# android - monitoring WiFi traffic and packets

Tags: android, networking, monitoring, packet-capture, network-traffic

I need to write an app which is going to connect to a specific WiFi network (given an IP address/name) and "listen" (monitor) to the network packets under that WiFi.

Eventually, I should be able to detect specific packets and act accordingly.

I want to write the app myself, so what tools/libraries are out there to monitor traffic? (stuff like PCAP.net in C#).

and one more question, is it possible for me to detect all the packets under that network? or just the ones that I send/receive?

thanks! just trying to see what libraries are out there and to hear from people with some experience...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android's TrafficStats class to monitor traffic.

From [Android Developer's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) about TrafficStats:

> Class that provides network traffic statistics. These statistics include bytes transmitted and received and network packets transmitted and received, over all interfaces, over the mobile interface, and on a per-UID basis.